# How to connect/authenticate to SSH server without any external librairies

Tags: c#, ssl, ssh, tcpclient, x509certificate2

Im trying to **connect to an SSH server without any external librairie** to basically prompt some commands or anything,

here is my skeleton code so far with the methods I want to implement, I would like to know if it is possible in that specific state:

```
private void TCP_Write()
{
    while (isRunning)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Connected)
            {
                Connect();
            }
            else
            {
                while (pendingCommands.TryDequeue(out string commandString))
                { 
                    //write commands to server
                }
                TCP_FlushEvt.Reset();
                TCP_FlushEvt.Wait();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Disconnect();
        }
    }
}

private void TCP_Read()
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (isRunning)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Connected)
            {
                //read reply and Debug it;
            }
        }
        catch /*(Exception e)*/
        {
            Disconnect();
        }
    }
    Disconnect();
}

private void Connect()
{
    try
    {
        TCP_Client = new TcpClient(computer.IpAddress, computer.IpPort)
        {
            NoDelay = true
        };
        TCP_Stream = TCP_Client.GetStream();
        TCP_Stream.ReadTimeout = Timeout.Infinite;

        //connect to ssh server

        if (!Connected)
            throw new Exception("Failed to connect.");

        if (!Authenticated)
            throw new Exception("Failed to authenticate.");

        TCP_pendingCommands = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Disconnect();
    }
}

private void Disconnect() { }
```

If somethign in't clear, feel free to bump it. I know it's a big question.

Comment: "connect to an SSH server using SslStream".  SSH is not based of TLS, so that won't work.

Comment: ok, that didn't know, then how do i connect to an SSH server in c# without using SSHnet, that's the whole problem ... SSHnet is too heavy for what I need :/

Comment: "basically prompt some commands or anything" what do you mean by "prompt some commands". Using an external library won't cause any prompt.

Comment: Either use an SSH library or write one yourself. SSH isn't SSL over Telnet, it's a completely different protocol. People use SSH tunnels *instead* of TLS. The [Wikipedia page on SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell#Architecture) says: `The functionality of the transport layer alone is comparable to Transport Layer Security (TLS); the user-authentication layer is highly extensible with custom authentication methods; and the connection layer provides the ability to multiplex many secondary sessions into a single SSH connection, a feature comparable to BEEP and not available in TLS.`

Comment: SSH in the form of OpenSSH is available as a feature in Windows and built-in in Linux and Mac. If you don't want to use a library you use the `ssh` command through `Process.Start`. SSH.NET is heavy because it has to implement an entire SSH client.